# Find local optimum (interval)

Tags: calculus, optimization

I review this local optimal part for my final exam.(for example, $ y = x^{3}$ )

so far,what I got

$ y = x^{3}$  has a point of inflection at $x=0$

$ f(x) = x^3 $ is concave up on the interval $(0, \infty)$ if the derivative $ f'$ is increasing and

concave down on the interval $ (-\infty, 0)$ if the 
derivative$ f'$is decreasing.

However, the questions is,

what if, I want to limit the open interval only  $ (-\infty,0)$.

if I draw the graph only the half side $ (−∞,0) $ is it still the same result?

and if it's a local maximum at $x=0$.

so far, I know that an absolute maximum is only possible within the closed interval.

therefore, $x=0$ is available only local maximum and not global maximum. 
is it correct? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by interval $(1,0)$? That can't be right

Comment: Derivative is always positive, what does this mean? Point of inflection is indeed at the origin

Comment: On the interval from negative infinity to zero, the Origin becomes an absolute maximum.

Comment: $0 \not \in (\infty, 0)$ so it cannot be the location of a local minimum in that interval

Comment: $x^3$ does not have any local or global maximum or minimum on the interval $(-\infty,0)$, or indeed on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: @Henry Yes, that is true. I should have been more clear on that. When the interval is open, of course, there is no maximum on my stated interval. I did not use bracket notation...

Comment: @Henry oh now i can get it. thanks. then,how about the critical point x=0 still exist?